# LeftJoin Minus (Right Table data + inner join Data)

Tags: mysql, sql

**TABLE 1)**
m_conservationsetting

```
+------------+-------+------------+
| FacilityId | Unit  | CategoryId |
+------------+-------+------------+
|     1      |    1  |      1     |
|     1      |    1  |      2     |
|     1      |    1  |      3     |
|     1      |    2  |      1     |
|     1      |    2  |      2     |
|     2      |    1  |      1     |
|     2      |    2  |      1     |
+------------+-------+------------+
```

Unique Key(FacilityId  Unit CategoryId)

**TABLE 2)**
l_maintelog

```
+------------+------+------------+--------+
| FacilityId | Unit | CategoryId | Status |
+------------+------+------------+--------+
|    1       |   1  |      1     |    0   |
|    1       |   1  |      2     |    1   |
|    1       |   1  |      3     |    0   |
|    1       |   2  |      1     |    0   |
|    2       |   1  |      1     |    0   |
|    2       |   2  |      1     |    0   |
+------------+------+------------+--------+
```

**Result :**

```
+------------+------+------------+
| FacilityId | Unit | CategoryId |
+------------+------+------------+
|     1      |  1   |     2      |
|     1      |  2   |     2      |
+------------+------+------------+
```

Table1 need to be left Joined  with Table2 and it should ommit the join results and show only table1 data as results.
Table1 LeftJoin Table2 - (join Data) for the below query. The condition for getting result is to check the status=0 for the record in Table2

**Query**

```
select cs.FacilityId,Cs.Unit,cs.CategoryId 
from m_conservationsetting cs 
LEFT JOIN l_maintelog ml on
(cs.FacilityId=ml.FacilityId and cs.Unit=ml.Unit)
WHERE (ml.Status=0
) 
group by cs.CategoryId
```

Comment: Try editing your question and provide sample data and desired results.  "[LeftJoin - (Right Table data + inner join Data)] " doesn't mean anything to me (at least).

Comment: @Gordon I just need the left Table data omitting the inner join data.

Comment: . . Let me repeat:  edit the question and include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NULL conditional on Second Table's Key column to eliminate result which is there in both tables

```
Select cs.FacilityId,Cs.Unit,cs.CategoryId 
from m_conservationsetting cs 
LEFT JOIN l_maintelog ml on
(cs.FacilityId=ml.FacilityId and cs.Unit=ml.Unit)
WHERE (ml.Status=0
and ml.FacilityId IS NULL) 
group by cs.CategoryId
```